# inside a Backbone.Marionette view render function I have Method that requires height value?

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, marionette, backbone-views

The Question is where in the Marionette view are you suppose to put a jquery method that doesn't require an event to instante it.

inside the view I have

```
onRender: function(  ) {          
            this.$('.loan-tool-bar').sticky();
            this.$('.sticky-wrapper').height(64);
  },
```

The above is working fine for me;

the problem is I want to set the height of `sticky-wrapper` based on the `height` of the `.loan-tool-bar`

so I tried this

```
   this.$('.loan-tool-bar').sticky();
   this.$('.sticky-wrapper').height(this.$(".loan-tool-bar").outerHeight());
```

this is giving the value of 0 on the sticky-wrapper

if i console log `$(".loan-tool-bar").outerHeight();` I get the value of 64

the problem is that the onRender is not getting the displayed value.

how can i solve this?

Comment: Does this view is being shown on a region? can you reproduce in a jsfiddle?

Comment: that is a good question @ekeren essentially that is the question the region gets into the dom after the onRender method. its too complicated sturcture to put a jsfiddle, what i want to know is if there is a post render method to invoke outerheight.

Comment: Resolved you need the onShow method to get it after the object and region is rendered in the dom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is already resolved in comments, but still this is a good enough answer to post:

The `onRender` is called after the view was rendered but it doesn't mean that the view is shown on screen in it's place and size. The solution is to setup size only after the view is shown by it's region/layout using the `onShow` fucntion.

Comment: onShow is only called if the view is handled by a region manager AFAIK. So for simple cases, it's just better to provide the el parameter to constructor, this way the onRender will be called when the view is already added to the DOM.

Comment: If you're using Marionette 1.8 you can also leverage [onDomRefresh](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.view.md#view-domrefresh--ondomrefresh-event) which is called every time the view updates the DOM (either a first render or future refreshes)